# WSDL2REST - is there a C# version? (convert SOAP to RESTful web service)

Tags: c#, java, web-services, rest, soap

converting a WSDL to a REST web service, Is there a C# version of this library?
http://wsdl2rest.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering if you really need a library for this? I mean as long as you have the WSDL you can create a service using the svcutil and decorate the methods with WebInvoke and WebGet also specifying the method (POST/GET/PUT) and the UrlTemplate. The methods would also have return types and input params based on your current wsdl.

I haven't tried it but I've been reading on the issue as my current project requires me to do so when I get that stage of our development effort...

Here are some sources: 
[How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)
["Reverse" WCF Service (Building a server from a client definition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527057/reverse-wcf-service-building-a-server-from-a-client-definition)
[How to use a WSDL File to create a WCF Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945620/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-proxy)

and so forth...